# Rotate Child Element From Parent:Hover

Tags: css, css-transforms

Just a small element that I can't seem to figure out and I'm hoping the collective knowledge here can point me in the right direction.

I'd like to rotate an image inside of a div when the user hovers over the div. An example of the code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/mashby/eCzmj/

Right now, the animation is triggered by hovering over the image itself, not the entire div.

Don't know if it's possible to do what I'm wanting to do, but thanks in advance for any confirmations, or suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with your CSS

You're using `#animate img:hover` which means that you will apply the styles to the `img` when it's hovered.

Try instead `#animate:hover img` to apply the styles to the `img` element when the parent `(#animate)` is hovered.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that, but you were 100% correct that it was my css gumming up the works. Thank you German!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. General idea:

```
#btnAgendaSettings img, #btnMinutesSettings img {
    transform: inherit;
}

.button-gray:hover, .button-gray:focus {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```